# Separating HTTP Response Body from Header in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, couchdb

## Extracting variable from callback with PHP and AngularJS

I'm building an app with AngularJS and Cloudant, and when I include a new document, the call back includes the revision number in the response, but it's all into a big string, like so:

```
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-Couch-Request-ID: cf04aa4a96
Server: CouchDB/2.1.1 (Erlang OTP/17)
Location: https://xxx.cloudant.com/xxx/xxx/1e829630-cdb6-463a-8c25-9cc140ff8ab0
Date: Wed, 04 Apr 2018 14:15:59 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 99
Cache-Control: must-revalidate
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Cloudant-Request-Class: write
X-Cloudant-Backend: bm-cc-uk-04
Via: 1.1 lb1.bm-cc-uk-04 (Glum/1.50.4)

{"ok":true,"id":"1e829630-cdb6-463a-8c25-9cc140ff8ab0","rev":"1-05a055a4f2e4baf71b46a14386eb7fab"}
```

How could I extract the rev from this string and save it in a variable?

I've tried this, but it doesn't work cause the response is a string containing an object...

```
$promisedb.then(function (datawop) {
    $scope.rev = datawop.data.rev;
}
```

Comment: which angular are you using? You just need to convert the string into an object... I can't remember offhand if angular has this built in... you could use.. `datawop = JSON.parse(datawop); $scope.rev = datawop.data.rev;`

Comment: **Describe the problem.** "It doesn't work" is not a problem statement. Tell us what the expected behavior should be. Tell us what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it. Put a brief summary of the problem in the title of your question.

Comment: In JavaScript/NodeJS you can convert stringified objects to normal objects with the builtin `JSON.parse()`  and also you can do the reverse with `JSON.stringify()`. I'm not sure about PHP, but probably there is something similar in PHP.

Answer (score 2):

HTTP headers are terminated by the sequence `\r\n\r\n` (a blank line).

```
$promisedb.then(function (response) {
    var splitArray = response.data.split("\r\n\r\n");
    var headers = splitArray[0];
    var body = splitArray[1];
    var data = JSON.parse(body);
    $scope.rev = data.rev;
}
```

Comment: Is the HTTP header termination represented the same on all platforms by JavaScript? I mean, on a Linux machine, should we use `\r\n\r\n` or just `\n\n`? Sorry, this may not be the smartest question.

Comment: [RFC2616](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#page-31) specifically states CRLF. Otherwise it is illegal HTTP/1.1.